# T-SQL: Pick a row where the value in a column is equal to, greater than or less than - but only one of these

Tags: t-sql, max, min

I have a table, called TableA with the following data in column ColA

```
ColA
100
60
50
30
10
```

I have a parameter called @colA

I want to select only one row. The criteria is such that if the value of ColA matches @colA, that row is returned. If no match is found, then it looks for the row where the difference between ColA and @colA is the smallest.

For example, if @colA = 50, the row with 50 is returned. If @colA = 58, the row with 60 is returned. If @colA = 33, the row with 30 is returned. If @colA = 200, the row with 100 is returned. Can this be done just using a Where clause and/or some Min/Max statements in the Select statement or would it be better off to be done with IF statements testing each condition?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to clarify why 33 returns 30, not 50. Your remarks about "where the difference is the smallest" are confusing. I guess if there is no exact match you want the number - either greater or smaller - where the absolute difference between @colA and that number is smallest? And what about ties (if you have any)?

Comment: The difference between 33 and 30 is smaller than 33 and 50. I always want the row where the value in ColA is larger than colA if the value of ColA does not match colA. However, there may not be a row where ColA is equal to or larger than colA. In that case, I will take the row where ColA is smaller in value than colA. There will always be a row regardless what the value of colA is.

Comment: I'm still confused: your comment basically says "I want the next highest number if there is one, otherwise the next lowest". So 33 should return 50, not 30?

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. According to my logic, 50 should have been returned and not 30. After thinking it over, I realized that taking the row with the least difference was a better way to go and thus Philip's solution was the best. I modified the question above to reflect his solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it in MS SQL Server 2008. Adjustments would be required for other RDBMSes.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (Data int not null)
INSERT #Test values (10), (30), (50),(60),(100)


DECLARE @Target int = 40

SELECT Data 
 from (select
          Data
         ,row_number() over (order by abs(@Target - Data), sign(@Target - Data) desc) Ranking
        from #Test) xx
 where Ranking = 1
```

The rigamarole with `sign` causes ties to be resolved for positive numbers (i.e. 40 woul return 50, not 30).

Comment: To get 50 chosen when @Target = 40, I just used sign(Data - @Target). Thanks a million. Wasn't aware of the sign function. Clever solution and definitely better than IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ColA INT
SELECT @ColA = 55

SELECT TOP 1 @ColA + TA.CA FROM
(
SELECT MIN(ColA) - @ColA AS CA FROM TableA WHERE ColA > @ColA
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(ColA) - @ColA AS CA FROM TableA WHERE ColA < @ColA
) AS TA
ORDER BY ABS(TA.CA)
```